# 409 (request "Conflict") when creating second Endpoint connection in MongoDB Atlas using Terraform

Tags: mongodb, terraform, endpoint, mongodb-atlas

I need to create many MongoDB Atlas endpoint connections using terraform.
I successfully create first, using this code:

```
#Private endpoint connection
resource "mongodbatlas_private_endpoint" "dbpe" {
    project_id = var.prj_id
    provider_name = "AWS"
    region = var.aws_region
}

#AWS endpoint for secure connect to mongo db
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ec2" {
  vpc_id = var.sh_vpc
  #service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.ec2" 
  service_name = mongodbatlas_private_endpoint.dbpe.endpoint_service_name
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.lb_sg.id,
  ]
  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.subnet1.id,
    var.sh_subnet
  ]
    tags = {
    "Name" = local.tname
  }

  #private_dns_enabled = true
}
```

But when I try to use this code second time in another folder (another tfstate) it failed cause error:

```
Error: error creating MongoDB Private Endpoints Connection: POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/***/privateEndpoint: 409 (request "Conflict") A PrivateLink Endpoint Service already exists for AWS region US_EAST_2.
```

As I understand, a second "mongodbatlas_private_endpoint" "dbpe" trying to create another one Endpoint service. But, when I creating second Endpoint manually through WebUI, it using the same service like first Endpoint.
How I can tell to second Endpoint to use the existing service?
Or maybe it all wrong?
Please, help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Creating the "Endpoint Connection" really creates Endpoint only when you do it at first time. All of next times is creating an only association between Atlas endpoint and new AWS Endpoint.
In terraform I tried to create an Atlas endpoint second time and catch an error (because of limit - 1 endpoint per region). All I need to do - is create "Basic Endpoint" one time (by separate folder with own tfstate) and don't delete it. And for each new AWS endpoint need to create a new link from AWS Endpoint to "Basic". I do it by a terraform resource:

```
mongodbatlas_private_endpoint_interface_link
```

Resource "mongodbatlas_private_endpoint" is not need now. A "service_name" parameter in "aws_vpc_endpoint" you can hardcoded from "Basic" Endpoint. Use "output" to see mongodbatlas_private_endpoint.test.private_link_id - this is what you need.